# how do i add new button in a custom object form

Tags: salesforce

I want to add a new button along with the standard buttons save, save new and cancel in custom object page.
Can we do it or do i have to write a VF page?

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create new buttons against the objects they are associated with, you then include them on a page layout. So you should be able to do what you want without needing to resort to a visualforce page.

Comment: just click on the related list in top left corner in page layout and drag the custome button on respected position